# indexOf give alternate return from same value after using splice

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof, splice

I make a function that checks if an array has a certain value.
If yes, then move it to the first element.
If no, write that value as the first element.
I use splice as a mean to both remove and add the value at the same time.

```
var ary = [6, 7, 8, 9];
var val = 5;

function myFunction() {
  var idx = ary.indexOf(val);
  ary.splice(0, 0, idx<0 ? val : ary.splice(idx,1));
}
```

It works well, but after further input of the same value, `indexOf` started to return value alternatively between 0 and -1.

I know how `splice` works, and I'm pretty sure that's not the problem.

I'm not asking about the answer to my problem. I just want to know what's wrong with my method.

Answer (score 0):

[`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) returns an array with the removed items.

You need to take the item of the array.

```js
var ary = [6, 7, 8, 9, 5];
var val = 5;
var idx = ary.indexOf(val);
ary.splice(0, 0, idx < 0 ? val : ary.splice(idx, 1)[0]);
//                                                 ^^^

console.log(ary);
```

Comment: Oh! How could I miss that spot?!
I forgot that splice returns an array. Thanks for the clarification!